# UITableView not scrolling issue

Tags: swift, uitableview, scroll

When I first load data into my tableview it doesn't scroll even when `UserInteractionEnabled` is true, but when I click on top of the tableview the cell scrolling gets enabled.

Does anyone know why this might be the case?

Answer (score 0):

UITableView could be tricky to answer. Let's check if you have few basics done right:

In Attribute inspector, make sure TableView has following

1- Scrolling Enabled is checked

2- User Interaction enabled is checked

Also in ContentView height is less than TableView in design

Let's start from these mentioned checks first

Comment: yeah basics are how the are supposed to be

Comment: what TableView Delegate methods you are using?

Comment: numberOfRowsInSection, heightForRowAt, cellForRowAt

Comment: Use numberOfSectionsInTableView to check if that changes anything

Comment: try reloadData in viewWillAppear

Comment: it doesnt work. but i do reloadData after i receive me data from the api anyway

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195311/discussion-between-saqib-raja-and-adam).